# Visual studio not finding spdlog.lib

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, compilation

I've been trying to create a simple project to understand the build process on Windows.
Recently, I downloaded and installed spdlog library, the folder of installation is located at

**C:\Program Files (x86)\spdlog**

with the following directories:

- bin: with the **spdlog.dll inside**;
- include: all **headers regarding spdlog**;
- lib: with two **subdirectories - cmake and pkgconfig** - and **spdlog.lib**.

I tried to link spdlog.dll with cmake to my code, but according to this [link](http://cmake.3232098.n2.nabble.com/How-to-link-against-a-dll-with-cmake-td5334151.html), dll files aren't linked, the suitable procedure is to link with a .lib file.

Well, with this last information I created the following CMakeLists.txt.

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

set(APPNAME DrumHero)
project($APPNAME)

#C++ version
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

set(SOURCES src/drumhero.cpp)
set(HEADERS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/drumhero.h)

set(DEPENDENCIES_LIBS spdlog)

link_directories("C:/Program Files (x86)/spdlog/lib")
include_directories("C:/Program Files (x86)/spdlog/include")

add_executable (${APPNAME} ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})

target_link_libraries(${APPNAME} 
                          PUBLIC ${DEPENDENCIES_LIBS})

set_target_properties(${APPNAME} PROPERTIES
    PUBLIC_HEADER "${HEADERS}")
```

When I try to build it Visual studio returns the error

**LNK 1104: Can not open file 'spdlog.lib'.**

I concluded that my main error is related to inform cmake where is the file 'spdlog.lib', but I don't know where exactly is the error.

I have 3 questions:

- Main question: How can I correct the CMakeLists.txt to link with spdlog?
- side question 1: .lib is similar to .a and .dll to .so?
- side question 2: Can't I link my code to a .dll file?

**Update 1**

I've already tried to escape the spaces in the path of spdlog, but it didn't work.

**Update 2**

Some comments raised the possibility that I might be mixing x64 with x86, so I decided to reinstall spdlog, now changing the architecture to x64.
The second installation was in Program Files, so I believe this time I used the appropriate path library: "C:/Program Files /spdlog/include".

But the problem remains.

Comment: `.lib` is used by visual studio `.a` is used by gcc and other compilers. In c++ many times you can't use binaries from a different compiler. Even the same compiler is incompatible with different versions. For example Visual Studio 2015 to 2019 are binary compatible but not compatible with any other version of Visual Studio. Related: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-160](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-160)

Comment: ***Can't I link my code to a .dll file?*** In Visual Studio using the msvc compiler you can't link dlls. You instead link the .lib import library for the dll. In mingw I believe you can link dlls but I don't know the limitations.

Comment: Are you mixing 32 and 64 bits by any chance?

Comment: Good point. `Can not open file 'spdlog.lib'.` usually means one or more of these: The library is not in the folder or named the way you say. 2. The library is corrupt, 3. You are mixing 32 and 64 bit.

Comment: In visual studio, I changed CMakeSettings. json to use x86-Debug, however the problem remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your build fails because you installed `spdlog` in a path that contains spaces. Try escaping the spaces:

```
link_directories("C:/Program\ Files\ (x86)/spdlog/lib")
```

As far as linking goes, on Windows, `dll` files are dynamic libraries, while `lib` files are static libraries.

There are two ways of using (linking) dynamic libraries on Windows: implicit and explicit. Both are documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/linking-an-executable-to-a-dll?view=msvc-160). If you built `spdlog` as a DLL the `spdlog.lib` you see is just an import library and the OS will load `spdlog.dll` when your application starts (if it can find the DLL).

EDIT: it turns out that debug builds of `spdlog` create a `spdlogd.lib` (notice the extra `d`). The author of the question had installed a debug build of the library.

Comment: This solution didn't work, the problem remains.

Comment: Have you by any chance installed the debug version of spdlog? In that case you should link with `spdlogd.lib`.

Comment: Genius. It solved!
Just a final question, what is the idea behind debug version and normal version?

Comment: I'll edit my answer to point this out. Long story short: Debug builds are easier to debug: the code is less optimized so it is easier to read the resulting assembly, some functions may work slightly different (some checks that are considered expensive may be done, for example), etc. In general, the code is slower, but it makes finding and understanding bugs easier.