# How to install spdlog library?

Tags: c++, cmake, libraries, spdlog

So I want to add logging to my c++ project, and people say spdlog is good.
I think spdlog has very clear installation instructions here:
https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/tree/v1.x
Clone the repo, create build folder and run cmake.
And then an example of a cmakeFile.
But I dont know cmake, and I know to little about libraries.

Cmake to my understanding is a file where you can specify everything needed to build a project. But it seems my IDE (currently codeBlocks for windows) does all that for me, so I have never learnt Cmake.

Libraries to my understanding is prebuilt classes/functions that I can include in my project.
I already use SDL in my project. To get that one to work I think I just ran some install program that created the library files like this
[image: SDL Folders]

and then I have added include path in

```
Codeblocks->project->build options->Search directories->compiler
```

and lib path in

```
Codeblocks->project->build options->Search directories->linker
```

and some settings in

```
Codeblocks->project->build options->Linker settings->other linker options
```

And then I can Include headers and use functions and classes.

What confuses me about the spdlog cmake file example (and the cmake in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66211808/visual-studio-not-finding-spdlog-lib)) is that they references external files (example.cpp and drumhero.h). Shouldent it just specify the spdlog files, and an output directory where the created library files will be put?
**Why does the library cmake need to know about my project files?** It should just create a library usuable by any project, not just mine.

I feel like I have fundamentally missunderstod something. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The CMake file at the link was written by the person to build their own code, and it also references spdlog to link it. Why do you think it's "spdlog's CMake file"?

Comment: But you don't have to do it this way (don't have to use CMake for your own project), just run the commands as specified in spdlog's manual and use the resulting binaries like you did with SDL2.

Comment: Ooooh, so I got it working. I only cloned the repo and then set the include folder in codeblocks project properties. Then I could include the header in code, and use the classes/functions.

I didnt have to add any library folder to the codeblocks project settings. In fact I didnt even find a lib folder in the repo. So I´m still confused why SDL needs lib files, but spdlog only nead header files.
So the cmake was just an example of how you could compile YOUR project. I thougth it was to compile the spdlog project, to create the library files, that you then could include in your own project

Comment: *"but spdlog only nead header files"* Because it can be used as a "header-only" library. But the readme says the normal mode (with libraries) gives you faster build times, so I'd investigate that. Also, obligatory reminder that you can grab prebuilt libraries from [msys2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075) (and then use `pkgconf` to automatically determine the correct compiler flags to use them).

Comment: I guess "header-only" is fine for me (since it works and does not feel slow). But if I wanted to use i the normal way I guess I should check the text under the caption "Compiled version" in the repo I linked.
Is that cmake file ment to create the library files, or is it ment to compile a project that uses the library files?
The caption implies it creates library files, but since the example contains "example.cpp" I feel like it compiles a project that uses the library files.

Comment: To compile the library you just run [these commands](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/tree/v1.x?tab=readme-ov-file#compiled-version-recommended---much-faster-compile-times). Their example `CMakeLists.txt` is for when you're also using CMake for *your* app.

Comment: Oh, my misstake was I thougth the two dots in "cmake .. && make -j" was a placeholder where you should insert your CMake filename. But it turns out its a valid command, and it worked for me (after I installed CMAKE).
The "&&" didnt work in powershell for me, but in normal windows cmd. "make -j" seems to be some linux thing. I checked codeblocks and tried to replace "make" with the file used there, so ""C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW_v11\bin\mingw32-make.exe" -j". But that just returns "mingw32-make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.". And I dont know what -j does.

Comment: Google tells me -j mean "jobs" and specify number of paralell threads https://askubuntu.com/questions/1295713/make-use-of-j-option.

But that does not make sense, so maybe that is a different "make -j".

There are plenty of .cmake files in the build folder. I dont know which should be specified.

Comment: You could try `cmake .. && cmake --build .`. It should call Make (or some other program) automatically.

Comment: Yes cmake --build . worked, thanks. It used MSBuild for .NET and created build/Debug/spdlogd.lib. I added the folder to linker search directories in codeblocks.
Compiling still works, but I´m pretty sure I still just use the header only version.
I then tried adding the lib file to project build options->linker settings->Link libraries (without really knowing what I´m doing) but that resulted in "undefined reference fprint" and similar errors with random characters instead of fprint. I also tried adding the -spdlogd to "other linker options", but that also resulted in error.

Comment: .lib is for MSVC compiler, not for MinGW. CMake defaults to MSVC on Windows. You could override that with ` -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++` (add that too `cmake ..`). Another good option is to reinstall your MinGW from [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075). They ship a version of CMake that defaults to MinGW (and they also ship prebuilt spdlog, among other popular libraries, so you could just download that).

Comment: I rather not reinstall, dont wanna break everything :)
cmake and the make suceeded. (make was also available for windows, guess I just didnt find it before, hard to google for "make":)).
This worked for me.
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="C:\Progr...\bin\g++.exe" ..
start "" "C:\Progr...\bin\make.exe" -j

I now get a "libspdlog.a" file in the build folder. I can add this to "link libraries" in codeblocks, and now the compile still works :) It still takes 25 seconds thou, so I suspect I still need to do something more for it to be actually used.